# Why aren't server-side changes being reflected in my app?

Tags: c#, php, win-universal-app

I have a simple C# Windows UAP project that uses a `HttpClient` to call a PHP script on a web server.  The script returns an XML document that contains some GUIDs (`*.xml` files with the extension omitted, leaving a GUID).  My app then uses that data.  If I make a change on the server, coincidently causing the PHP script to return different data, my app still uses the old data (to be exact, it does this until the app is restarted).  If a call the script using a browser, the data appears how I expect it to, but the app doesn't do what it should with the data.  It almost seems like the first response is being cached.

Here's an example:
Say I start with one file in the folder where my PHP script finds all *.xml files (`eef8401a-b5cd-4da7-ad36-0fb7a8fa6c62.xml` in this case).
The script should and does return:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<eventlist>
<id>eef8401a-b5cd-4da7-ad36-0fb7a8fa6c62</id>
</eventlist>
```

When I run the app, its response is the same.
So far, all is working as it should.
However, say I add a new XML file in the folder (now `eee8401a-b5cd-4da7-ad36-0fb7a8fa6c62.xml` and `eef8401a-b5cd-4da7-ad36-0fb7a8fa6c62.xml`).  The script returns just like I expect it to:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<eventlist>
<id>eee8401a-b5cd-4da7-ad36-0fb7a8fa6c62</id>
<id>eef8401a-b5cd-4da7-ad36-0fb7a8fa6c62</id>
</eventlist>
```

The app's response this time is still the previous one (with only one `id` element).
This persists until the app restarts.  After that, it works like it should--until I make another change in the folder.

Here's my PHP script:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/xml');
    $handler = opendir('C:\path\to\folder\\');
    $ids = '';
    while (($file = readdir($handler)) !== FALSE) {
        if (strpos($file, '.xml') !== FALSE) {
            $ids .= '<id>'.str_replace('.xml', '', $file).'</id>';
        }
    }
    closedir($handler);
    exit('<eventlist>'.$ids.'</eventlist>');
?>
```

And my app's C# code:

```
    public static async Task<string> ContactServer(ApiMethod m, IProgress<double[]> prog, params KeyValuePair<string, string>[] args) {
        using (var client = new HttpClient()) {
            var path = m.ToString().ToLower() + "/"; // in this case, is 'list/'.
            //...
            // other stuff, omitted for simplicity
            //...
            var fullUrl = "http://example.com/path/to/api/" + path; // in this case, is 'http://example.com/path/to/api/list/'.
            var d = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(fullUrl));
            var data = await d.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Debug.WriteLine(data);
            return data;
        }
    }
```

Again, my PHP script works fine, but my app gets a different response than I do when I run the script in my browser manually.
Why is this happening?

Comment: You realize that `closedir` is never called because of `exit`, right? (even thou I don't think it's related to the problem)

Comment: @AlanMachado That was a stupid mistake on my part.  Thanks for the find

Comment: Are you using Windows.Web.Http or System.Net.Http?

Comment: @o0rebelious0o `Windows.Web.Http`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Runtime which provides the HTTPClient has a very aggressive webcaching strategy to save user's bandwidth.  Unless your server explicitly sets a cache duration header, it will return all** requests with the same Uri directly from the cache without even contacting your server.

You can turn off this behaviour by:

Setting a cache duration header (cache-control: no-cache, etc.).

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url.ToString());
if (request.Headers == null)
    request.Headers = new WebHeaderCollection();
request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
```

Adding a random number to your requests query string.

```
string uri = "http://host.com/path?cache=" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

Or, as CodeCaster suggested, you could also avoid the caching by using the `If-Modified-Since` header

```
HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
if (request.Headers == null)
    request.Headers = new WebHeaderCollection();
// Make sure that you format time string according RFC.
request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.IfModifiedSince] = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("r");
```

or you can add to every request the client makes with

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.IfModifiedSince = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("r");
```

Using `Windows.Web.Http` you could also use

```
var httpFilter = new Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
httpFilter.CacheControl.ReadBehavior = 
    Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpCacheReadBehavior.MostRecent;
var httpClient = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient(httpFilter);
```

** I have said all requests, but I don't know if that is strictly correct, I will take a look and check and update here, though CodeCaster has suggested `GET` and `HEAD` only; I have certainly seen on `GET`, unsure about others off the top of my head

Comment: _"all requests"_ - are you sure? Not just GET and HEAD? And you can also circumvent this by adding the `If-Modified-Since` request header, which will make it a conditional request, bypassing the cache.

Comment: You could be right, I'm not 100%... Definitely seen with `GET`, I don't know for definite about other verbs... Can update if someone can refine or say for definite

Comment: Works like a charm!  Thanks!